# Calculate Average Distance Between All Points in Radius and Reference Point (R)

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, buffer, r-sf

I have spatial data and would like to create a new column in my dataframe that calculates the average distance to neighboring coordinates within a radius of my choice.

I found this code that gets me kind of close:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

# three semi random cities in NC
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

#Buffer of 2 arc degrees around Greensboro
buffer <- sf::st_buffer(cities[2, ], 200000)

# Draw Leaflet map
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>% 
  addPolygons(data = buffer) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(data = cities, 
                   color = "red",
                   fillOpacity = 2/3,
                   stroke = F)

# Count # of coordinates in radius
count <- sf::st_join(cities, buffer, left = F) %>% 
  nrow()
```

I want to be able to modify this code with the adjustable radius and say, when I used X as the radius, the average distance between Greensboro and whatever other points are captured in the circle is = 15.4 miles.

Can someone help point me in the right direction of how to solve this problem?

Thank you! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, not sure if I understand your problem so let me rephrase it. You have a data frame with a number of points, one line = one point. 

1. I take a point (ether one from your data frame or a new one), call it A
2. I create a buffer around it 
3. I count the number of point inside of it
4. Give the value to the point A

Am i Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be most easily done using the sfdep package.

The idea is to create a neighbor matrix using a distance band. Then, with those neighbors, find the distances from the focal point. Lastly, iterate over the resultant list column to calculate the average.

```r
library(sf)
library(sfdep)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

# three semi random cities in NC
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  as_tibble() |> 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)


cities |> 
  mutate(
    nb = st_dist_band(geometry),
    dists = st_nb_dists(geometry, nb),
    avg_dist = purrr::map_dbl(dists, mean)
  ) 
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -79.81944 ymin: 34.22333 xmax: -77.91222 ymax: 36.08
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   name                   geometry nb        dists     avg_dist
#> * <chr>               <POINT [°]> <nb>      <list>       <dbl>
#> 1 Raleigh    (-78.63333 35.76667) <int [2]> <dbl [2]>     148.
#> 2 Greensboro    (-79.81944 36.08) <int [1]> <dbl [1]>     112.
#> 3 Wilmington (-77.91222 34.22333) <int [1]> <dbl [1]>     184.
```

Comment: This looks great! However, I am having issues with the sfdep library.  Is it possible to frame this problem using a different library?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: My R won't install it.  Asks me to install RTools first, then RTools can't be found either.

Comment: @user2813606 follow the instructions at https://rstats.wtf/set-up-an-r-dev-environment.html#windows-system-prep rtools is important for windows users.

Comment: IT dept won't let me install Rtools on my computer so I need an alternative.  Is it possible to get the desired result above using the spdep library?

Comment: the above result is using spdep. you need rtools to install spdep. You shuold ask your IT department how other people install software such as python packages that need compilation